# Solve an inequality involving entropy of random variable X

Tags: inequality, information-theory, entropy

Im working through Elements of Information Theory and came across a question which is stumping me. The problem states Let $p(x)$ be a probability mass function. Prove, for all $d\ge0$ that $$\text{Pr}(p(X)\le d)\log\frac1d\le H(X)$$ Where $H(X)$ is an entropy. The presence of the $log\frac1d$ term makes me believe that this is related to a change of base as $H_b(X)=\log_b(a)H_a(X)$ but I can't see why the Pr$()$ term would be related to entropy in any way. Any help on the actual method to solving this is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality), which says the following: let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable and $a>0$, then $Pr(X \geq a) \leq \mathbb{E}[X]/a$. In this case, let the random variable $X$ be $-\log p(X)$. Then an application of Markov's inequality gives, for all $a>0$:

$$P(-\log p(X) \geq a) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[-\log p(X)]}{a} = \frac{H(X)}{a}$$

Now, set $a = \log \frac{1}{d}$, so that we get

$$P(-\log p(X) \geq \log \frac{1}{d})\log \frac{1}{d} \leq H(X)$$.

Finally, notice that $-\log p(X) \geq \log \frac{1}{d}$ is equivalent to $p(X) \leq d$.

Comment: Aha! Thank you. At a glance I could also do this with X=log(1/p(x)) with assumptions about how it behaves at x=0 right? Thats been the more natural choice for me as I learn about entropy

Comment: $\log (1/p(x)) = - \log p(x)$

Comment: Right but 1/p(x) has an undefined value for p(x)=0 so we have to add assumptions no? ie the coeffecient of 0 takes precedence by my estimation